# SpringBoot BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultInstance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, beancreationexception

I have a SpringBoot + Maven project with JPA. When tring to run the application I got the following error stack.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultInstance
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
> at com.pasindu.dockerexample.DockerExampleApplication.main(DockerExampleApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultInstance
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletCookieValueMethodArgumentResolver.(ServletCookieValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:40) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.getDefaultArgumentResolvers(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:648) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:561) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
> ... 17 common frames omitted
> Process finished with exit code 1

Below is my pom.xml file.

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
     <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
 <artifactId>docker-example</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>docker-example</name>
 <description>Docker Example</description>

 <properties>
     <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
         <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                 <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                 <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
         <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
         <version>1.18.12</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
         <version>8.0.18</version>
     </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
     <finalName>app</finalName>
     <plugins>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
     </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

Any idea of how to fix this ?

Answer (score 5):

The problem described is related to conflicts between different Maven dependencies. I've had the same problem while trying to use the latest version of Spring Boot with Apache Camel.

After analyzing the dependency tree, it turned out that the version of spring-webmvc was 5.2.9, while all other spring dependencies were of version 5.2.8.

In my case, I have solved the problem by using a newer version of camel-spring-boot-dependencies (3.6.0, unlike previously used 3.5.0).

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution.

In my pom.xml there were two dependencies like

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

What I did was removed the **spring-web** dependency and reloaded all Maven Plugins and tried running the project again.

It was successful.

Comment: I have the same problem but I don't have **spring-web** as a dependency :( And I see this after upgrading to spring 5.2.9 :(